# Winforms ComboBox Bug?

Tags: c#, winforms

Winforms ComboBox Shows {value=value, key=key} even if I already set the DisplayMember and ValueMember. Is this a known bug?

I have 2 Comboboxes, lbSelectedGroups and lbAvailableGroups, both of them are bound to  `List<Role>` and `List<UserRole>`, respectively, through a BindingList.

Both of them will be populated in the constructor, but usually only lbAvailableGroups contains data. When I try to add an item(onclick) on lbSelectedGroups, in which data comes from lbAvailableGroups, it shows {value=value, key=key}.

Comment: What? What is the issue you are having? Can you supply more details? Code sample?

Comment: I have 2 Comboboxes, lbSelectedGroups and lbAvailableGroups, both of them are binded with List<Role> and List<UserRole>, respectively through BindingList.

Both of them will be populated on the constructor, but usually only lbAvailableGroups contains data. When I try to add an item(onclick) on lbSelectedGroups, in which data comes from lbAvailableGroups, it shows {value=value, key=key}

Comment: Could probably do with a more descriptive title here - a little vauge :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your list contains KeyValuePair collection (probably came from some dictionary) instead of UserRole objects.